# Is there any good reference for RxAndroid specific documentation?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

Is there any good reference for RxAndroid specific documentation ?  Where  I can get reference to objects like AndroidSchedulers ,AndroidObservable and ViewObservable. Am looking more for API kind of documents.

Have checked following urls and not finding android related details there.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/wiki

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki

http://reactivex.io/intro.html

Comment: Currently RxAndroid is just `AndroidSchedulers`. You can find javadocs to it [here](https://static.javadoc.io/io.reactivex/rxandroid/1.2.1/rx/android/schedulers/AndroidSchedulers.html). Any other stuff related to the reactive programming specific to Android platform, have been moved to separate libraries.

Comment: @BartekLipinski - thank you, its really good pointer at least I know now  some part doesn't exist the way I have expected .. when you said moved to separate libraries, are these libraries are RxLiffeCycle and RxBinding ? please share url if you have similar to AndroidScheduler.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a API kind of documentation, but it covers all the API is a simple tutorial fashion..

- [Crunching RxAndroid — Intro](https://medium.com/crunching-rxandroid/crunching-rxandroid-intro-c27eb6f009ea)
- [Crunching RxAndroid — Part 1](https://medium.com/crunching-rxandroid/crunching-rxandroid-part-1-4ac7b7123238)
- [Crunching RxAndroid — Part 2](https://medium.com/crunching-rxandroid/crunching-rxandroid-part-2-fb2a86f4fb8d)
- [Crunching RxAndroid — Part 3 -10](https://medium.com/crunching-rxandroid)